# Generic plural. I need to know if there is a rule about it

Tags: adjectives, singular-vs-plural, generic-noun-phrases, nominalization

We say "the poor"  but then we say "the Italians". If both are correct, I wonder why is not possible to say "the poors". Can you tell me the rule please?

Comment: "Poors" is not a word. Any dictionary can tell you that. "The doctor" becomes "the doctors"... you can't pluralize a non-count noun.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Poor* is an adjective.

Sometimes we use an adjective such as *poor* as if it were a noun. But when we do, we mean *the poor* as a class of people, meaning *the poor ones*. Even without the word *ones*, *the poor* is considered plural. So we do not add an *s* to it.

The ony way to make *the poor* singular is to put a singular noun after it: *the poor boy*. If you wanted to refer to more than one *poor boy* you could say *poor boys*.

Adjectives that work this way include *poor*, *rich*, *meek*, *wealthy*... [Grammarly](https://www.grammarly.com/answers/questions/78201-noun/) lists the following examples as adjectives that work this way:

> aged, educated/uneducated, injured, powerful, unemployed, blind, elderly, living, rich, weak, brave, free, needy, sick, wealthy, dead, handicapped, old, starving, wounded, deaf, homeless, oppressed, strong, young, disabled, hungry, poor.

However, other adjectives used as nouns *can* mean a single person or thing: *the former*, *the accused*, *the deceased*. We have the option of putting *ones* after them and they will be plural: *the former ones*. But we still would not say *the formers*. In general, adjectives--even when used as a noun--cannot be pluralized.

So, yes, *the dead* is plural and is short for *the dead ones* and *the deceased* is short for *the deceased one* and is usually singular (but it can be plural: *the deceased ones*.). There is no rule, to my knowledge, for why this is so, other than how the language has developed over time.

Adjectives that refer to nationalities follow a different pattern.

*Italian* is used as both a noun and an adjective. In *the Italian boy* it is an adjective. In *the Italian played a great game* it is a noun. I think really the only way we know this is that you can pluralize it: *The Italians played a great game*. Not all names of nationalities work this way: it is rare to see *the English* used as a singular noun.

Comment: Thank you very much Alan, your answer has been very useful.